# POCO C++ library: connect to server with HTTPS or HTTP

Tags: poco-libraries

I am using the `POCO::Net::HTTPClientSession` class to connect to the web server on IoT devices. I now need to support HTTPS to the device, but whether its HTTP or HTTPS is a configurable parameter in the device profile that may change at runtime.

I can connect just fine on HTTPS using the `HTTPSClientSession` class, and I can obviously connect on HTTP using the `HTTPClientSession` class. But I rather not use two objects for the two protocols. It seems I should be able to use the `HTTPSClientSession` object for both, since class `HTTPSClientSession` is a subclass of `HTTPClientSession`.

When I attempt to use an `HTTPSClientSession` object to talk to a plain HTTP server listening on port 80, The `HTTPClientSession::sendRequest` method throws exception `Poco::Net::NetException` with the message:

```
140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol
```

Is it appropriate to be trying to use the `HTTPSClientSession` object for HTTP? If so, what do I need to do?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can't use `HTTPSClientSession` for HTTP communication. But you can make use of the fact that `HTTPSClientSession` is a subclass of `HTTPClientSession`:

```cpp
std::shared_ptr<HTTPClientSession> session;
if(https) {
  session.reset(new HTTPSClientSession());
}
else {
  session.reset(new HTTPClientSession());
}
```